# How to ensure value masking happens immediately when input type = password, without delay on a phone?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm working on a project wherein I have 5 input boxes of type password and after every input has been entered, the control goes to the next box.

But only after 3 or 4 inputs have been entered, are the previous digits getting masked. There is a delay of about 3-4 seconds only after which the key is getting masked.

Initially, I thought that it might be because of the keydown/keyup functions linked to the input boxes, but the masking delay is happening even after I removed all key events.

One thing I noticed was the same issue isn't occurring on a desktop, but it's happening only on mobile.

```html
<div class="pin-div" id="form-group-id">
  <input name="pin" class="pin-inp" tabindex="0" type="password" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" id="pin-a">
  <input name="pin" class="pin-inp" tabindex="0" type="password" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" id="pin-b">
  <input name="pin" class="pin-inp" tabindex="0" type="password" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" id="pin-c">
  <input name="pin" class="pin-inp" tabindex="0" type="password" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" id="pin-d">
  <input name="pin" class="pin-inp" tabindex="0" type="password" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" id="pin-e">
  <input name="pin" class="pin-inp" tabindex="0" type="password" maxlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" id="pin-f">
</div>
```

The same delay in masking the digits is happening even after I used input type = "tel"

What is the best way to ensure that there is no delay in masking inputs?

Comment: Isn't that default behaviour?

Comment: Why isn't it occurring on a desktop device? And is there a way to mask it immediately on a phone?

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't it occurring on a desktop device?

Because it's harder to type on a phone, where you're covering a tiny on-screen keyboard with your fingers which tries to make a best guess estimation where your meat nubs intended to hit the screen most likely. You pretty much *need* the visual confirmation to ensure you didn't mistype that key. It's the default behaviour of the phone, for those reasons.

Typing on a large physical keyboard on a desktop device has none of those issues and the visual feedback isn't as necessary. It's also a lot easier to cover a tiny phone screen by simply turning away for a second than it is to do the same thing on a desktop device.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way mobile browsers currently handle password inputs, accounting for both security and usability issues which obviously have different challenges compared to non-mobile browsers.

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password

> Specifics of how the entry process works may vary from browser to browser; mobile devices, for example, often display the typed character for a moment before obscuring it, to allow the user to be sure they pressed the key they meant to press; this is helpful given the small size of keys and the ease with which the wrong one can be pressed, especially on virtual keyboards.